# Replace Appcelerator Application database on iOS

Tags: javascript, sqlite, appcelerator-titanium

Hy, I have an iOS application (only for iOS) developed in Titanium Appcelerator using JavaScript.

I'm trying to use SQLite data bases in my app.

I was able to copy my SQLite database to my project with this:

```
Ti.Database.install('/baseDados/aquarismo', 'AquaInfo');
```

This "/baseDados/aquarismo" is the database directory inside my project, and "AquaInfo" is the name of the database after copying it.

Then I can open and close my database to get my data from it.

My problem is when I update my SQLite database I need to update it inside my project. So I replace my database inside my project folder with the new database.

But then I need to delete the old database when my app starts and replace it whit the new one.

I have tried this:

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(
Ti.Filesystem.applicationSupportDirectory, 'database','AquaInfo.sql');
//If it's there, delete it
if(f.exists() == true){
     f.deleteFile();
}

// Install fresh database
Ti.Database.install('/baseDados/aquarismo','AquaInfo');
```

However the database doesn't get replaced by the new one.

How can I update my SQLite database when my iOS app starts?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you update database whether update your table column or create new table and save your changes, new "AquaInfo.sqlite" file generated.

So we have to replace it because we are updating database from external source.

***Solution:***

If you want database changes at application starting point. You have to  write code manually like create table, add column in manual created table and change data type of certain column.

So you can achieve this via manually write code for creating table and related stuff.